# Custom post type show on both Home and Date Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

Found below snippet to pull posts from a custom post type 'pictures' into the home page and date archive page..

Added to `functions.php` this works for home page:

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'pictures') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

But this works for neither:

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_date() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'pictures') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

Would also like to add in `!is_admin()` to keep the admin screens clear, and not sure how to go about that.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `( $query->is_home() && $query->is_date() && $query->is_main_query() )` always returns `false` because `$query->is_home()` and `$query->is_date()` cannot be `true` on same page.
Try this,

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin()  &&  $query->is_main_query() ) {
       if ( $query->is_date() ||  $query->is_home()  ) {

           $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'pictures') );

       }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Just superb! thanks Qaisar

Comment: @MatJon Stay blessed!

Comment: @MatJon if this worked for you, then mark this answer as "Accepted Answer" to help other people searching for similar solution.